# How to execute code when running Entity Framework Core code-first Add-Migration command?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have the need in a .NET Core 2.2 project to run a small bit of code (load environment variables from a .env file) when I run an Add-Migration command. Is there anywhere in my project I can put this code so that it runs before the migration is created? I read somewhere that Startup.Configure gets executed but that's not the case. The fact that I need to set the startup project when creating the migration implies that something is getting executed.

To clarify the reasoning, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

In my Visual Studio solution I also have a docker-compose project. I use a .env file (so it can be added to .gitignore) to populate the environment. I want to use the same .env file to setup the environment for the .NET projects to avoid duplicating entries in, for example, an appsettings file. I found a Nuget package that works really well for loading .env files at startup so the code side is covered. The problem is that when I try and add a migration, I can't run this package to import the .env file which contains the connection string data so the migration add fails.

Comment: Looks like XY problem, can you explain why you need to run some code when you adding a migration? Notice that add-migration will just generate a migration file, which you can modify afterwards (together with the snapshot)

Comment: @Fabio Sure, I've added more explanation to my question.

Comment: Can the add migration command wait until the other stuff is done?

Comment: Depends on how you create a DbContext. For complicated cases you can implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`. Here is a link for more details how EF Command line tools instantiate DbContext https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Fabio's comments above I was able to figure out the solution from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) article that I somehow missed. In my case I am creating the app using IWebHostBuilder. In this situation, Design-time tools like migrations make a call to CreateWebHostBuilder in Program.cs. In order to load my environment variables from the file, I had to chain a call to ConfigureAppConfiguration, where I then load the environment variables from my .env file. And yay, now I have one place for environment variables that's used by Docker Compose and the .NET project.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).
                ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    // Load the contents of the .env file into the environment variables
                    // Necessary to do this in ConfigureAppConfiguration so design-time processes (eg. migrations) have the environment settings.
                    DotNetEnv.Env.Load("../../.env");
                }).
                ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {
                    ...
                }).UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```